# Exclude a control from UpdatePanel Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I want to exclude a button in UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="row contact-person">
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex mt-3 yerlestir">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbYetkiliEkle" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" OnClick="lbYetkiliEkle_Click"><span><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></span>Yetkili Ekle</asp:LinkButton>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" type="button">Vazgeç</button>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnKaydet" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Kaydet" ValidationGroup="unvan" OnClick="btnKaydet_Click" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kaydet ve Yeni Ekle</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have two buttons. I want to exclude the "btnKaydet" button. Is this possible?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbYetkiliEkle" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" OnClick="lbYetkiliEkle_Click"><span><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></span>Yetkili Ekle</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Button ID="btnKaydet" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Kaydet" ValidationGroup="unvan" OnClick="btnKaydet_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can exclude `btnKaydet`. For that you can use the `PostBackTrigger`.
btnKaydet will now trigger a full PostBack.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        contents

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnKaydet" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```